# add view to the parent view from a subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I have my rootviewcontroller. in that I load view A. 
View A containts a button to load view B. however, I don't want to add view B as a subview of view A. which happens if I do this:

```
- (IBAction)loadViewB:(id)sender {

    if (self.viewB == nil) {
        self.viewB = [[NUMViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NUMviewController" bundle:Nil];
    } 

    [self.view addSubview:viewB.view];

}
```

I want to load viewB as a subview of my rootview. so I can animate out viewA before animating in viewB.

but I'm not sure how I must approach this. I'm guessing I need a method in my rootViewController to handle the adding and removing of the subview. I would need to be able to call that method from within my viewA subview.

any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `[self.view.superview addSubview:viewB.view]`
But I don't think this is the best approach as it comes to MVC.
What can you do is add viewA to self.view and viewB to self.view also.

Comment: thanks this worked. but I'm not sure I understand the adding of viewA and B to self.view. how do I then animate one in and the other out? and is self.view the view of my rootviewcontroller or are we talking about a container view where I assign viewA and B into?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Here is the scenario. You have a root view controller, which has a main view (self.view). Add two UIView properties to the root view controller (viewA and viewB), initialize them and add them as subviews to self.view (root view controller's main view). Then you can use the properties to control them, animate them and whatever you like. Don't forget to release them in the dealloc method (if not using ARC). (Actually your properties could be UIViewControllers, which you initialize and add their views to your self.view).